# Swift Round up / Max the NSDecimalNumber

Tags: swift, max, nsdecimalnumber

Let's say we have an `NSDecimal` constant called `total` and it contains the value of 3.33333333 divided by 10/3. 10 and 3 are both `NSDecimalNumber`.
We want the total to be 4 as an `NSDecimalNumber` in Swift.

```
let total = ten/three

// the ideal total would be rounded up whenever there is a floating
```

in the doc. we have

```
func NSDecimalRound(_ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSDecimal>,
                  _ number: UnsafePointer<NSDecimal>,
                  _ scale: Int,
                  _ roundingMode: NSRoundingMode)


maximumDecimalNumber()
```

Which one is the best fit for calculator with currency style? Please include an example each how to use them if you know so. Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let x = NSDecimalNumber(string:"10")
let y = NSDecimalNumber(string:"3")
let total = x.decimalNumberByDividingBy(y).decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior( NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: NSRoundingMode.RoundUp, scale: 0, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false))   // 4
```